# Where can I find a repository containing functionaljava 3.0?

Tags: maven, functional-java

I would like to use functional Java [3.0](http://functionaljava.org/download/) in a maven project. I have been googling a little, but I can't find valid information to include the corresponsding 'dependency' in my pom.xml.

Someone [mentioned](http://groups.google.com/group/functionaljava/browse_thread/thread/2bc8b030f358f2eb/7ecce5bcb12eb5de?#7ecce5bcb12eb5de) that he would upload the artifacts to the scala-tools maven repository, but it does not seem like he followed-up on his announcement.

It does not even seem that earlier versions of functional Java are available from maven.

Does anyone have valid and recent information about this issue?

Thanks!

P.S.: Yes, I know I can download and manually include the .jar in my project, but this is only a workaround solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fact is, I don't like to manually include .jars in repositories, because it is not a distributed solution.

I have copied the functional java code in a maven 'repository' project called 'externals' and it compiles fine. I can generate the artifacts and have no need to upload them manually anymore.

Comment: Fair enough. Had I known that you have a repository available, I'd have suggested this also :-)

Answer (score 5):

Version 3.0 is now in Maven Central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/functionaljava/functionaljava/3.0/

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any maven distribution. But here's a small shell script that will install the jar and the sources in your local repo.

Unpack the zip distribution and execute this script from inside the unpacked directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

# edit these to suit your needs
GROUPID=org.functionaljava
ARTIFACTID=fj
VERSION=3.0

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=$GROUPID -DartifactId=$ARTIFACTID \
    -Dversion=$VERSION -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=functionaljava.jar

cd src/main

jar cf src.jar *

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=$GROUPID -DartifactId=$ARTIFACTID \
    -Dversion=$VERSION -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=sources -Dfile=src.jar

rm src.jar
```

(Windows version would be very similar, probably just replace `$this` with `%this%`, maybe prepend `CALL` to the maven calls)